# An Everyday Task

Tags: riddle

> Most children need help and they take it quite slow,
>
> It's only done once by the man on the go,
>
> The carefullest sort do it twice in a row,
>
> Before going out in the rain or the snow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hazard of a guess is:

> Tying shoes

Reasoning:

> Kids need help with it
>  if you are rushing you don't have time for proper double knotting.
>  Double knotting is what the careful folk do
>  This is where it gets tenuous: snow boots often have laces. Stereotypical rain boots less so but...
>  An everyday task: It is often portrayed as something one does when they get ready to go out the door each morning.